# Is my answer actually correct?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I posted one of my first answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636051/python-script-creating-functioning-loop/41636145#41636145) (Python), which got downvoted twice straight after I posted it, as it didn't actually loop the way the OP wanted it to. I thought that I should post it at that point, because if the OP wanted a quick answer, he could work the final part out himself. I then finished the post with the correct looping, but then it got a further down-vote.

I am not asking for loads of people to up/downvote the original question or my answer, but I would like to know if my answer is actually correct.

Comment: Looking at your answer in general, it's quite acceptable. You've given code examples and you've given a good description that supports the code. I can not verify if it's true or not. All I can say is that, if you believe what you wrote is right, then leave the answer. Maybe someone in the future might find some use for it and they will upvote it. Downvotes don't always mean what you wrote is wrong, but may mean that someone doesn't agree with you.

Comment: Do know that voting isn't an indication if an answer is *correct*, it indicates if an answer is useful. Correct answers might not be useful in the context of the question.

Comment: @rene, That's interesting, I only sort of knew that, so thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It seems odd to ask Meta whether your answer is correct. The best people to answer that would be the experts who visit questions tagged [python], which are the same people who will see and vote on your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Python, but since you've asked on Meta...

Looks like question lacks valid MCVE and should not be answered till one provided. Guessing actual question always bears risk of getting question completely wrong which results in downvotes.

First revision of the answer did not show any loops at all - clearly not an answer - deserved downvotes and should have been posted as comment (see another recent Q on Meta [Answering a question without giving the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341625) ). Even in current version of the answer first (main) part of the answer still focuses on "you need to use functions" - which sounds absolutely not necessary and very unlikely actually answer the question. It is generally better to provide answer first and additional styling comments at the end of the answer or as comments.

It looks like code relies on adding two images - I'm not sure if such operation naively exists in the language and if it does what OP needs. This may hint to lack of MCVE in the question - how one would know what `canon.FetchImage(0, 1 * 1)` returns?